# Using QT; QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I am using vtk QT, i've installed VTK, PCL libraries well, after run the project the realese mode; i found the following error.
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you will need to create a [QApplication](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qapplication.html) before you can instantiate and use a [QWidget](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qwidget.html). For example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>                                                        
                                                                                                                                                       
int main(int argc, char *argv[])                                                
{                                                                               
    QApplication app(argc, argv);                                               
    QDialog dialog;                                                              
    dialog.setModal(true);                                                      
    dialog.show();                                                              
    return app.exec();                                                          
}
```